# Lying in the Job C.V and haram money

Tags: halal-haram, money

Firstly,

I was wondering previously that many people lie about themselves in their job CV. As the person is getting job on the basis of his/her qualifications in the CV. So, as he is getting hired on the basis of the lies doesn't it make the money that he earns from that job Haram.

Secondly,

If a person earns haram money but does not spend that money for his own and gives it to the poor does that still make him a sinner?

Comment: These are two separate questions. They should be asked separately (or not even asked if it already exists).